# Extract text between two strings but only the first occurrence using sed?

Tags: shell, sed, sh

So I Have a string which looks something like this :

```
<tag>Hello world </tag> blah blah blah <tag> Good night !! </tag>
```

I only need to extract hello world. Any idea how to frame the sed command ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using simple cut :

```
echo "<tag>Hello world </tag> blah blah blah <tag> Good night ls -ltrh cptrade* </tag>" | cut -d'>' -f2 | cut -d'<' -f1
```

Answer (score 1):

Crude but effective:

```
sed 's|</tag>.*||;s|.*<tag>||'
```

"Remove everything from the first `</tag>` onward, then remove everything up to and including the last (and presumably only remaining) `<tag>`."